# Easy Image Hosting

Tags: images, html

Sorry for the most basic question. I'm looking at the code for my first website right now.
I'm just creating a portfolio page for my Illustration works, as an excuse to learn.

I want someone else to be able to simply open the HTML file and check what I've made, meaning that I need to host the images of the page somewhere online.
Is there a good place online where I can host images for free and with reasonable file size limits? As far as i know most image host sites will push hard for paid plains (fair enough).

Comment: You can pay for your own hosting for as little as $5 a month. It's a very wise investment in your own career. Not only can you host images yourself, you can customize your email.

Comment: Currency exchange really makes it not worth it right now, i just need something to hold my things until i'm actually able to get my first website done.

Comment: @NandoAguiar surely there are servers in your local country. But if you really can not afford ~5$ a month your going to die form upgrade of your computer. As your computer costs something between 16-84 $ per month where 50$ is somewhat reasonable. So in reality you should put 50$ away each month fore a new computer